# Using “will” to talk about now

Tags: modal-verbs

I saw this sentence in a book:

> Don't phone Ann now. She'll be busy. (= she'll be busy now)
>
> -- [*English Grammar in Use*](http://books.google.com/books?id=8fOT2TIO4yIC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44) by Raymond Murphy.

I don't understand why the sentence uses future tense for “She'll be busy.”

I'm wondering if I can write “Don't phone Ann now. She is busy.” instead or not.

Plus, “she'll be busy” means she may be busy or not.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but I think it's a matter of implying a hypothetical future. I'd read it as **“If** you call her, she **will** be busy.” It's also a bit of a hedge, as the speaker does not mean to convey that he or she has perfect knowledge of Ann's availability (which would not be possible in this situation).

Comment: If, however, the speaker were standing next to Ann, and Ann was midwifing the delivery of a rhino calf, the speaker might say (to anyone elsewhere) “Do not call Ann. She is busy.” because at that point the speaker is willing to claim full knowledge that Ann is not available for calls.

Comment: English doesn't have a future tense.  The modal auxiliary *will* **can** express future time, but it doesn't do so directly, so other interpretations are often possible (or required).  Again, I'll link to [What's will?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=897) on Language Log, as it'll do a better job of explaining than I would.

Answer (score 3):

In OP's context, the future tense *verb form* doesn't necessarily imply any direct reference to a future *time*. For example, there are several hundred written instances in Google Books of...

> [*[He] will be asleep **now***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22will%20be%20asleep%20now%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...where obviously the word *now* implies present, not future time. But it's important to note that native speakers often use *He **would** be asleep now* in exactly the same context, with exactly the same meaning.

In my example, you could interpret *will* as implying something along the lines of *it **will become apparent** [in the near future]*, and *would* as implying the [irrealis/subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood#Subjunctive) *if it **were to be** definitively established*.

But in practice I don't believe native speakers think that way. It's just that using the "future" tense places a bit more "distance" between the *speaker/time of speaking* and the referent. For example, [Stanley's famous greeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Livingstone) could have been (but wasn't, I believe)...

> "You **will be** Dr. Livingstone, I presume?"

Depending on the exact context, the precise nuance imparted by introducing *You will be* in such a construction may vary. For example, it could convey *respect* (you are different/**more** important than others in the presently-assembled company), or *disrespect* (you are different/**less** important than them).

---

Having said all that, the use of future tense in OP's exact context *usually* implies you *believe or expect* your statement ***will*** be verifiable. If Ann had only just told you she'd be busy for at least the next hour, you'd use present tense (because you ***know*** she ***is*** busy).

Comment: And then there's "You will be Dr.Livingstone, at the Halloween party, I presume?"

Comment: Come to think of it, sir, can I use "would be verbing" for inference? e.g. She would be swimming = She will be swimming? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Kinzle: You can indeed, but ***should*** (often contracted to ***'d***) won't necessarily work equally well in all contexts. It's a bit more "formal, deferential, hesitant" than ***will***, which is sometimes appropriate. Other times it can add a "slightly sarcastic" tone (effectively "inverting" the standard formal implications). Incidentally, native Anglophones would not normally address anyone as ***sir*** except in very formal contexts (or when talking to a customer in a "service" role such as restaurant waiter, shop sales assistant, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

In imaginative sentences, if we are certain about something then we use 'will' else 'would.'

In the given context, the speaker is not in the direct vicinity of Ann. So, he is not saying '**Ann is busy**,' instead he is imaging that '**Ann will be busy**.' The speaker is certain about it. After an hour or so, the conversation would continue like this- 'Can I phone Ann now?' 'I guess. **She would be free now**.'